# Horror, thriller manga/manhwa about a girl who suicided ended up being a ghost, hoping to escape the realm by achieving the specific time

Tags: story-identification, manga, horror, ghost

I can vaguely remember seeing this Manga/Manhwa on a Facebook page about 4, 5 years ago and I haven't finished reading it so I only remember the first few parts. Also I tried to search the page for it but apparently it was gone missing.

Here it goes.

---

The story starts with a small scene where an unknown man goes to a fortune telling lady only to be told by the lady that there has been a ghost following him. Then, the story briefly displays the daily life of the girl, the main character, working and living with her mother. She wears typical office worker style. On that fateful day, her boss decided to have her drunk then violate and take advantage of her afterwards. Being shameful after the incident, the girl decided to take her own life by climbing to the roof of her office building and freefalling to her death.

After that, the girl found herself waking up in the public park where she always went with her mother. Confused, she tried to get help from someone else but neither anyone can hear nor see her. It was at the moment, she met a boy. He could see her and they had lots of chats. The boy called himself as the 'Guidance' for her and told her that the only way to get out of this place was that she had to keep her good spirit level at high and when the clock tower at the park stroke at 7:00AM (or 9:00AM or 11:00AM) **[This is the crucial detail of the story that I really don't remember - In addition, the time mark is also included in this Manga/Manhwa's title]**

The girl was confident that she would easily pass this 'test', then the boy informed the girl that there was a catch. He said **"Don't let the Red Man affect you. He can not hurt you but his bad influence can affect your spirit level, which will delay the time progress to the goal time mark. If you let the Red Man successfully impact on you, you will end up being the ones like him."**. Even worse is that the Red Man's influence might reverse the girl's progression.

One day, as the girl has been keeping her spirit level high and steadily climbing her progress, the boy said that he could not be able to accompany with her any longer, which makes her pretty upset because they have been very good friends. The boy carefully advised her again and believed that she would make it through and defeat the Red Man's bad omen. Then they parted ways and the boy was never to be seen again...

---

And this was where I left off the last time. I'm hoping someone reading this post will have a clue about this manga/manhwa's title so that I can enjoy it again! Thank you very much!

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: @LogicDictates It was mixed. I remember some pages were fully or partially colored, others are black and white. The Red Man however, was coated entirely in red.

Comment: Do you recall if it was a traditional page-based layout, or a long-strip webtoon? Also, you explicitly mention manhwa - it is possible it's a Chinese manhua?

Comment: @qazmlpok Possibly might be a Manhua. When I saw it, it was translated and posted on Facebook so I don’t know if it was long-webtoon strip or traditional page-based style. Furthermore, the Facebook page that posted it didn’t state the art form so I don’t know whether if it was manga/manhwa/manhua. If only they did, my search could have been narrowed down very much.